# WhatsApp Automation using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, block, whatsapp

I'm automating WhatsApp messaging on WhatsApp Web using selenium in python.
The code is working all fine. It's sending out messages.
But is there any way, i can use it to send Bulk messages using WhatsApp.
I tried, but I ended up whatsapp blocking my number.

Comment: https://lesmartomation.com/send-whatsapp-messages-with-automated-script-using-selenium/ this might help you

Comment: @AmrutaPande I already have the code, sending text to thousands of people, but the problem is the number getting blocked.

Comment: I also have this issue

Comment: Coding Invasion, How are you sending message to 1000 people ? by loop or group ? Also recipients are all new non saved ?

Answer (score 0):

For sending the bulk message you can use a loop and can use a time delay for sending the messages in a specific time delay.
Or for getting help with code you have to share your code.

You can use any virtual number to use for your bot, So you not have to worried for getting blocked by whatsapp. There are some apps which are providing free virtual numbers.

By the way I have also created a whatsapp bot for automate whatsapp messaging and I have used that number for 1 year to test the working and progress of automation and have used much and still that number is not get blocked by whatsapp.

Comment: If wanted to send 100 messages and put delay of 30 second then it will take around 50 minutes to send last message which doesn't seems a solution

Comment: If you want to send only 100 messages then you can use time.sleep(0.25) delay with python. I think its much time to get typing a message and send it.